# How to pass 2D map as a pointer to function

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I have 2 maps:

```
map<int, map<int, int> > m1;
map<int, map<int, int> > m2;
```

And want to fill them in with a function:

```
void fillMaps (m1, m2) {
    * m1[0][0] = 5;
    * m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

How should i pass those maps to the function?
I guess the variable itself can be passed just like this:

```
map<int, map<int, int> > m1;
map<int, map<int, int> > m2;

fillMaps(m1, m2);
```

But how should i define types of variables inside the function to be able to change values of the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the maps in the function you'll want to pass them by reference:

```
void fillMaps (map<int, map<int, int> >& m1, map<int, map<int, int> >& m2) {
    m1[0][0] = 5;
    m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

Note that there are spaces between the close angle braces to prevent weird compiler errors.  Also note that with the pass by reference, you don't need to use any pointer dereferences; this is handled automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the maps by reference or pointer to modify the values.

```
void fillMapsByReference (
    std::map<int, map<int, int> >& m1,
    std::map<int, map<int, int> >& m2)     {
    m1[0][0] = 5;
    m2[0][1] = 4;
}

void fillMapsByPointer (
    std::map<int, map<int, int> >* m1,
    std::map<int, map<int, int> >* m2)     {
    *m1[0][0] = 5;
    *m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe everybody chooses reference approach.  In my opinion the pointer approach is strongly preferable because it is explicit.  See Google C++ guide -- "all parameters passed by reference must be labeled const".

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a bit different answer from others. You can use C++ templates and make the compiler automatically infer the types for you:

```
template <typename T>
void fillMaps (T& m1, T& m2) {
    m1[0][0] = 5;
    m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
map<int, map<int, int> > m1;
map<int, map<int, int> > m2;

fillMaps(m1, m2);
```

This way you pass the maps by reference. Also, if you later change the type of the maps (for example using another map implementation or using strings instead of ints), you won't have to change this function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typedef` to make the code cleaner:

```
typedef map<int, map<int, int> > intmap;

void fillMaps(intmap &m1, intmap &m2)
{
     m1[0][0] = 5;
     m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

Comment: See pointer arguments approach below by @Leonid.  It is better, writable pass by reference is not a good style in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value by reference. Also, you need to declare the type of m1 and m2 in fillMaps.

```
void fillMaps(map<int, map<int,int> > &m1, map<int, map<int,int> > &m2)
{
     // fill map code in here
     m1[0][0] = 5;
     m2[0][1] = 4;
}
```

Then, to call use `fillMaps(m1, m2);`

Comment: Works in C++0x, but be careful that the code sample is not a valid C++ 2003 code - >> is illegal in template specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
template <typename T>
class MapOfMaps
{
  public:
    // ...

  private:
    map<T, map<T, T> > m;
};

typedef MapOfMaps<int> MapOfIntMap;

void fillmap(MapOfIntMap& m1, MapOfIntMap& m2)
{
//...
}
```